# Alert auto close usando Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, alert

Usando Bootstrap e criei um botão <kbd>save</kbd> no qual executa uma função específica `selector()`. Esta função será executada somente depois que salvar no banco, então mostrará uma alerta que desaparecerá em de uns instantes. No entanto está sendo executando somente uma vez e não mais. (sei que é algo extremamente simples)

```js
function selector() {
  $(".alert").removeClass('hidden');
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
  }, 4000); 
}
```

```css
body{
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="alert alert-success hidden" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Congratulations!</strong> Saved successfully!
</div>

<button style="margin: 10px" type="button" onClick="$(selector).click()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#category">save</button>
```

Como tem que ser feito para que o alerta apareça toda vez for executado a função `selector()`?

Comment: Porque não usa toastr ? É bem mais fácil e prático.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda parece uma alternativa. vlw

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você está passando uma função chamada `selector` como um seletor `onClick="$(selector).click()"`, e só funciona porque o jQuery tenta resolver o qualquer função como um callback para obter a string, ou seja está errado, bastaria isto:

```
 <button style="margin: 10px" type="button" onClick="selector()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#category">save</button>
```

Tem dois problemas:

1. `.remove` exclui o elemento, então não tem como exibir depois
2. `.fadeTo` adiciona opacity (do CSS) igual a `0`, quando iniciar a animação novamente é necessário setar como `opacity: 1;` para remover a transparencia, você pode usar o proprio fadeTo, ficará assim:

```js
function selector() {
  $(".alert").fadeTo(1, 1).removeClass('hidden');
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(".alert").addClass('hidden');
    });
  }, 1000); 
}
```

```css
body{
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="alert alert-success hidden" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Congratulations!</strong> Saved successfully!
</div>

<button style="margin: 10px" type="button" onClick="selector()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#category">save</button>
```

Nota que se clicar muitas vezes pode dar erro, então use .stop:

```js
function selector() {
  $(".alert").stop().fadeTo(1, 1).removeClass('hidden');
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(".alert").addClass('hidden');
    });
  }, 1000); 
}
```

```css
body{
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="alert alert-success hidden" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Congratulations!</strong> Saved successfully!
</div>

<button style="margin: 10px" type="button" onClick="selector()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#category">save</button>
```

> Eu vou editar a resposta mais tarde, porque acho que sendo bootstrap-3 isso vai falha, já que a API deles usa o role e o target para o controle dos elementos